# How can I call the variable **Servo::write** in Arduino for my 360 servo?

Tags: servo, button

I'm trying to control a **Servo** with a **push** **button** and to help me watching if it is working I am using a **LED** but I'm not sure if I'm doing it well the **Servo::write** so I need you to tell me what am I doing wrong that my **Servo::write** function its not working but the **LED** does the function. Here is the code I am using:

```
#include <Servo.h>


Servo myservo;

const int  buttonPin = 2;    // the pin that the pushbutton is attached to
const int ledPin = 13;       // the pin that the LED is attached to
const int serPin = 9;

// Variables will change:
int buttonPushCounter = 0;   // counter for the number of button presses
int buttonState = 0;         // current state of the button
int lastButtonState = 0;     // previous state of the button

void setup() {
// initialize the button pin as a input:
pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
myservo.attach(serPin);
// initialize the LED as an output:
pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
// initialize serial communication:
Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop() {
// read the pushbutton input pin:
buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

// compare the buttonState to its previous state
if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {
// if the state has changed, increment the counter
if (buttonState == HIGH) {
  // if the current state is HIGH then the button
  // wend from off to on:
  buttonPushCounter++;
  Serial.println("on");
  Serial.print("number of button pushes:  ");
  Serial.println(buttonPushCounter);
} else {
  // if the current state is LOW then the button
  // wend from on to off:
  Serial.println("off");
}
 // Delay a little bit to avoid bouncing
delay(50);
}
// save the current state as the last state,
//for next time through the loop
lastButtonState = buttonState;

Servo::write(myservo);

// turns on the LED every four button pushes by
// checking the modulo of the button push counter.
// the modulo function gives you the remainder of
// the division of two numbers:
if (buttonPushCounter % 2 == 0) {
 digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
 myservo.write(serPin < 180);
} else {
 digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
 myservo.write(serPin > 0);
}

}
```

Comment: I think you should look at some servo examples in the IDE. You will then see that you have done the servo code completely wrong.

Comment: (in fact your code doesn't even compile).